# Swift4 unit testing: ViewController not found when type casting

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, swift4

I am currently writing test on a `MyViewController` class with the following code:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController")
XCTAssertNotNil(viewController.view)
XCTAssertNotNil(viewController as? MyViewController)
```

This test does not work, the second assert always fails. When I debug, I can see my `viewController` has the correct type, but it looks like the type casting is always failing.

```
(lldb) po viewController

MyProject.MyViewController: 0x7f900c835600

(lldb) po viewController as? MyViewController

nil
```

The code of `MyViewController` and the storyboard are correctly included inside the Test project. There is also Cocoapods included.

I tested on an empty project and the issue remains present.

Does anyone has the same issue? Am I missing something?

**Edit**. I change the code to this:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as? MyViewController
XCTAssertNotNil(viewController)
```

But the issue is still present.

Comment: Did you `@testable import YourModule` ??

Comment: Your pasted code works fine for me, obviously swapping in my storyboard/view controller names!

Comment: @testable import MyProject is set. If I explicitly call MyProject.MyViewController instead of MyViewController, the test works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this (I used ViewController throughout):

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
XCTAssertNotNil(viewController.view)
XCTAssertNotNil(viewController as? ViewController)
```

That test passed!

So I tried your second way of writing it:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(
    name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(
    withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController
XCTAssertNotNil(viewController)
```

It passes on my machine!

If it's not passing for you, it might be because:

- you failed to do a `@testable import` of your main module, or
- you have an ambiguous class and you needed to say `as? MyProject.MyViewController`, or
- the view controller with that identifier was not found, or
- the view controller with that identifier is not a MyViewController

But, regardless, the test is *telling you the truth* and you need to think about that truth. You have not given *us* enough information to know which of those is your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test by replacing your test with :

```
    XCTAssertTrue(viewController is MyViewController)
```